# Method that will set properties and values in a JS object

Tags: javascript, prototype

Given an object like:

```
var house = {
 bedrooms: 4,
 baths: 2,
 city: "Austin",
 details: {
  price: 500000,
  closing: {
   date: "May 7"
  }
 }
}
```

I'm trying to create a method that would let me set an existing property's value or, if the property doesn't exist, create a new property with that value.

Therefore inputs could be:

```
house.setProp("details.closing.date", "June 1");
house.setProp("details.newProp", "newProp Value");
```

Output would be:

```
var house = {
 bedrooms: 4,
 baths: 2,
 city: "Austin",
 details: {
  newProp: "newProp Value",
  price: 500000,
  closing: {
   date: "June 1"
  }
 }
}
```

This is my attempt so far, and while it works for the first depth, I can't figure out how to access/create multiple depths. Can you help please? Thanks!

```
Object.prototype.setProp = function(path, newValue)
{
  var keys = path.split('.');
  obj = this;

  if (keys.length > 1)
  {
      setProp(obj[keys.shift()], newValue);
  }
  else
  {
      obj[keys[0]] = newValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: You seem to want a loop, not a condition. Or did you mean to use recursion?

Comment: you need to use recursion

Answer (score 1):

```
var house = { 
 bedrooms: 4,
 baths: 2,
 city: "Austin",
 details: {
  price: 500000,
  closing: {
   date: "May 7"
  }
 }
}
house.details.closing.date= "June 1";
house.details.newProp="newProp Value";
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to see how to format code correctly (`<br>` is not it).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access a static property, you don't need to do anything special

```
house.details.closing.data = "June 1";
```

However, if you have a dynamic list of properties, you can use [dotty](https://github.com/deoxxa/dotty) to accomplish this easily

```
var dotty = require("dotty");
dotty.put(house, "details.closing.date", "June 1");
```

Equivalent to

```
var dotty = require("dotty");
dotty.put(house, ["details", "closing", "date"], "June 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it with `reduce`:

```
var setProp = function(path, value, obj) {
  path = path.split('.')
  path.reduce(function(acc, k, i) {
    if (i === path.length-1) {
      acc[k] = value
    } else if (typeof acc[k] !== 'object') {
      acc[k] = {}
    }
    return acc[k]
  }, obj)
  return obj
}

var o = {a: {}}
setProp('a.b.c', 1, o)
console.log(o) // {a:{b:{c:1}}
```